# mongoose.Types.ObjectId returned an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
const orderfoodSchema = new Schema({
  _id: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
  name: reqString,
  quantity: reqInt,
  price: reqInt,
});
```

and then I want to save it like this

```
const order = new Order();
  order.key_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
  order.id_table = (
    await Table.findOne({
      id_table: {
        $nin: (
          await Order.find({ status: "not paid" })
        ).map((id) => id.id_table),
      },
    })
  ).id_table;
  order.date = new Date();
  order.total_cost = 0;
  order.status = "not paid";
  await order.save();
```

but it throws an error that _id can't be an Array now why would the mongoose.Types.ObjectID returns an Array and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define _id for the schema. It will be auto-generated in MongoDB. Try to remove _id from your schema or remove [] from your schema. try to code like `_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId` would not generate an array of ids.

Comment: ah yeah.... I forgot that the schema is wrapped inside in a [] thanks for helping me out tho